# activating dynamic named excel file

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies if this is too easy to ask;

I have an Excel file which has a dynamic Name under this code:

Code for saving file with dynamic name.

```
Dateiname = Ord & mNummerGanz & "_" & Name & ".xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dateiname
```

After saving this file with a dynamic Name, i want to open another Excel file, copy a range from this file and then paste it on my dynamic named file.
Windows("Dateiname.xlsm").Activate gives an error.If i put Windows(Dateiname).Activate it still gives an error. Dateiname variable is in different module then Windows.Activate, how can i call this variable then ?

Does anyone have solution for this Problem ?

Comment: Assuming it's the same application, try `Workbooks(Dateiname).Activate`.

Comment: it is in different module, what should i do to make my module know what Dateiname actually is ?

Comment: Either pass it as an argument to your other routine or declare the variable `Public`. The latter isn't great practice but probably easier if you are a VBA newcomer.

Comment: so how do i declare the variable as public?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to open a file named `Dateiname.xlsm`, but a file with named stored in `Dateiname` variable. Then, use `Windows(Dateiname).Activate`.

Comment: it is in different module, what should i do to make my module know what Dateiname actually is ?

Comment: Declare it in the first line of module, before any `Sub` declaration.